# How to make a class template specialization for reference and non-reference types?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class called `Pen`:

```
class Pen {
    int m_color;

public:
    Pen(const int &color) 
        :m_color(color) {}
};
```

and I want to have a class called `Drawable` that stores a `Pen`. If the user passes in an lvalue reference of a `Pen` to the constructor of `Drawable` then I want to store that `Pen` as a reference inside `Drawable`. If I get an rvalue reference I want to store that `Pen` as an new variable inside `Drawable`.

In other words if I get an already existing variable then I want to store it as a reference otherwise copy (or move) its stuff into a new variable.

I want to do this so that if the user changes any properties of the `Pen`, these changes should also be reflected for the `Pen` inside my `Drawable` automatically.

This is what I managed to come up with so far:

```
template<bool isRef>
class Drawable {};

template<>
class Drawable<true> {
    Pen &m_pen;

public:
    Drawable(Pen &a)
        :m_pen(a) {}
};

template<>
class Drawable<false> {
    Pen m_pen;
    
public:
    Drawable(Pen &&a)
        :m_pen(std::move(a)) {}
};
```

However when in this case the user has to specify true or false each time which I find kinda inconvenient. Is there a way this could be automated, either by using templates or something entirely different?

Just a side note. This will be a Base class for other shapes.
C++ Standard: Any. Will be using C++20 most of the time.

Comment: How about store a `std::shared_ptr<Pen>`, and the user can give `Drawable` an existing pen or a new one?

Comment: Pretty sure that user-specified deduction guides (C++17 required) can do this.

Comment: @Kevin Correct me if I'm wrong but then they'll have to pass in a std::shared_pointer or a normal pointer right? And that way they wont be able to pass in an temporary.

Comment: @MayankShigaonker I made an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way that suits my needs and that is basically the combination of @Kevin's answer and @Sam Varshavchik's comment on the question. So I'm using `std::shared_ptr` with Class template argument deduction guides. Here's my solution:

```
template<typename> // Base Condition 
class Drawable {};

/* Lvalue */
template<>
class Drawable<Pen &> {
    Pen &m_pen;

public:
    Drawable(Pen &a)
        :m_pen(a) {}
};

/* Rvalue */
template<>
class Drawable<Pen &&> {
    Pen m_pen;
    
public:
    Drawable(Pen &&a)
        :m_pen(std::move(a)) {}
};

/* Shared */
template<>
class Drawable<std::shared_ptr<Pen>> {
    std::shared_ptr<Pen> m_pen;
    
public:
    Drawable(std::shared_ptr<Pen> pen)
        :m_pen(pen) {}
};

/* These guides help out the compiler determine the right specialization */
Drawable(Pen &) -> Drawable<Pen &>;
Drawable(Pen &&) -> Drawable<Pen &&>;
Drawable(std::shared_ptr<Pen>) -> Drawable<std::shared_ptr<Pen>>;
```

All this is, is 3 specializations for the 3 cases I want to support and guides to help the compiler decide which 1 the compiler should pick. Now the user can pass in a existing or temporary Pen or a existing or temporary `std::shared_ptr` to a Pen and everything just works without the user having to specify any template arguments.

To remove repeating code just move it into a base class and then inherit from it in all 3 cases.

By the way that template argument doesn't have to exactly match what you're passing in. I just made it that way to make the code more readable (ig). You can also get away by doing something like this.

```
template<int>
class Drawable {};

/* Lvalue */
template<>
class Drawable<1> {
    Pen &m_pen;

public:
    Drawable(Pen &a)
        :m_pen(a) {}

    Pen &get() { return m_pen; }
};

/* Rvalue */
template<>
class Drawable<2> {
    Pen m_pen;
    
public:
    Drawable(Pen &&a)
        :m_pen(std::move(a)) {}

    Pen &get() { return m_pen; }
};

/* Shared */
template<>
class Drawable<3> {
    std::shared_ptr<Pen> m_pen;
    
public:
    Drawable(std::shared_ptr<Pen> pen)
        :m_pen(pen) {}

    std::shared_ptr<Pen> &get() { return m_pen; }
};


Drawable(Pen &) -> Drawable<1>;
Drawable(Pen &&) -> Drawable<2>;
Drawable(std::shared_ptr<Pen>) -> Drawable<3>;
```

Here instead of using types are template parameters I'm using numbers also don't use this method as you don't understand whats going on. This was just an example to demonstrate a point.

So now you `main()` can look something like this:

```
int main() {
    Pen ref(69);

    Drawable a(Pen(69));
    Drawable b(ref);
    Drawable c(std::make_shared<Pen>(33));

    ref = 420; // Now the Pen inside Drawable is also 420
}
```

Thanks for the help @Kevin, @Sam Varshavchik and @Aconcagua

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use a shared pointer. This has a benefit of there being a single `Drawable` type (vs `Drawable<true>` and `Drawable<false>` being separate types). `Drawable` doesn't need to know or care whether there's another owner of the pen:

```
class Drawable {
    std::shared_ptr<Pen> m_pen;
public:
    Drawable(std::shared_ptr<Pen> pen): m_pen(pen) {}
};
```

A user can make a `Drawable` with a pen that it changes later:

```
auto pen = std::make_shared<Pen>(...);
Drawable d(pen);
pen->setColor(...);
```

Or with a new pen that it gives to the `Drawable`:

```
Drawable d(std::make_shared<Pen>(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll keep this in mind as a last option maybe as I want the experience as seamless as possible. Meaning the user should be able to just give their parameter and everything will be handled for them. I'll research a bit more on user-specified deduction guides as per  @Sam Varshavchik and if I find nothing I'll go with this :)

Comment: @MayankShigaonker Be aware of *ownership*. `Drawable<true>` doesn't own the pen, meaning that the pen can be destroyed before the drawable (which would be bad if you tried to use it after that point). `Drawable<false>` has full ownership of the pen, meaning the pen will be destroyed when the drawable is. In my answer, `Drawable` *shares* ownership of the pen with whoever else has a shared pointer to it. Whether this answer works for you depends on which of these kinds of ownership you want.

Comment: Hmm your point is right. I should've thought about lifetimes. I think I might end up going your route then but I'll think about this a bit more. Thanks a lot for this help :)

Answer (score 0):

They are different types anyway, so why not simply remain with one single template and have helper functions to create the proper one?

```
template <typename Pen>
struct Drawable
{
    Pen pen;
};

Drawable<Pen&> makeDrawable(Pen& pen)
{
    return {pen};
}

Drawable<Pen> makeDrawable(Pen&& pen)
{
    return {std::move(pen)};
}
```

Getting the appropriate type with `auto` is just as simple then, too:

```
Pen p;
auto d1 = makeDrawable(p);
auto d2 = makeDrawable(Pen());

std::cout << typeid(d1).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(d2).name() << std::endl;
```

Output on my system (linux, gcc):

```
    8DrawableIR3PenE
    8DrawableI3PenE
```

Comment: Huh how did I not think about this. This is exactly what I needed but because of the comments about lifetime in the previous answer I'm staring to re-think my choices. Thanks a lot anyways. This might be useful somewhere else :)

Comment: @MayankShigaonker Ownership is an important issue. Depending on how complex the `Pen` is it might be simpler just to *always* copy it. On the other you might change settings for all `Drawable`s or groups of at once if they can share a common `Pen`. Design issue. Sharing even with ordinary references is no problem if you ensure by other means that the shared object is not destroyed too early. `shared_ptr` relieves you from such considerations, but comes with some runtime overhead.